# Why when adding a contextmenu to richtextbox i need to make twice right mouse button click to see the menus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {   //click event
        //MessageBox.Show("you got it!");
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

        richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
    }
}

void CutAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Cut();
}

void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
}

void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        richTextBox1.Text
            += Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();
    }
}
```

when I mark a text in `richTextBox1` and make right mouse button click on the marked text it does nothing only on the second time it's showing the menu.

If I'm not marking any text when running the program and make mouse button right click it will scroll down and will select the last text on the bottom of `richTextBox1`.

And another sub question is how can I put the `contextmenu` creation code in form load event. So, it will create the `contextmenu` only once when running the program and not each time i make right mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on the first click, you add the `ContextMenu` and on the second click it is available. This means, when you first right-click the `RichTextBox` there is no `ContextMenu` attached to it. Move the code to Form_Load or the constructor (Or even better, add the context menu in the designer). MopuseClick events don't need to be handled to show the `ContextMenu`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

    richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}

void CutAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Cut();
}

void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
}

void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        richTextBox1.Text
                += Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();
    }
}
```